# AWS word press site missing content after EC2 reboot

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I deployed wordpress site on EC2 and connected it using RDS mysql. Everything works perfect on the first run and as long as EC2 and RDS are running. As soon as i stop the ec2 and rds and try to reboot it next morning or straight away, i can get to word press site but content is not layed out properly and images are missing too. I searched through internet and found closely related issues which recommend using of elastic ip, i also used elastic ip and assign that to EC2 but still content of WP is missing. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is embedding your website URL, or IP address if you don’t have a stable DNS name, in its configuration file and database.

Any change of the IP addrsss or DNS name after the initial installation will cause the behavior you’re seeing.

This page doc has the steps to fix that. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

The below script directly changes the IP address in the Wordpress database. Be sure to change `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DB_HOSTNAME=`grep DB_HOST /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php | cut -d ',' -f2 | awk -F "'"  '{ print $2 }'`
WP_URL="http://`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname/`/wordpress"
DB_USER=wordpress
DB_PWD=password
DB_NAME=wordpress
mysql -u $DB_USER --password=$DB_PWD -h $DB_HOSTNAME $DB_NAME -e "UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='$WP_URL' WHERE option_name='siteurl' OR option_name='home'"
```

You can run this script automatically at boot time to adjust the DB to the new IP address of the EC2 instance.

Note that the long term solution is different : I would recommend to use two EC2 instances for availability and a load balancer.  The load balancer will have a stable DNS name (that you can alias with a CNAME record in your domain DNS).  The Wordpress database would include that CNAME name only.

See this whitepaper for best practices to deploy Wordpress on AWS : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/wordpress-best-practices-on-aws/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, when i installed wordpress on aws ec2 instance, i have created some posts and pages, and after some time i have stopped ec2 instance. When started ec2 instance, wordpress site did not showing contents.

So the Solution was i found is that, wordpress require static IP address, so i have created new ec2, assigned Elastic IP address to the ec2 instance and created wordpress blog, it worked fine for me even restarting the ec2 multiple times.